# Laravel pre-filling multiple forms if validation failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

One of the coolest Laravel feature is, Laravel pre-filled the form fields if validation error occurred. However, if a page contain `more than one form`, and form fields have `same name`, Laravel pre-filling all `forms fields`.

**For example:**

I have a page where i have two forms to create new users or whatever.

```
<h1>Create user1</h2>    
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
        {{ Form::text('name', null) }}
        {{ Form::email('email', null) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}

</h1>Create user2</h1>    
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
        {{ Form::text('name', null) }}
        {{ Form::email('email', null) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

**Controller**

```
class UsersController extends BaseController
{
  public function store()
  {
     $rules = [
        'name'   => 'required',
        'email'  => 'required'
    ];

     $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

     if ($validation->fails()) {

        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
     }
  }
}
```

[image: Fill up form1 - no email]

As i didn't fill up the email, Laravel will throw validation error and pre-filling the forms as following:

[image: pre-filled two forms fields]

**How to tell Laravel that do not fill-up the second form?**

Comment: Your interface is bad in terms of UX. What if user fills both forms but clicks only on last "Add" button?

Comment: @neoascetic , they won't as in real application they will know that forms are different.

Comment: @neoascetic,  In real application, I have to create forms by using dynamic info.(based on total results i get from a table). if i have 10 results, i have to create 10 forms and it is make sense that to use single controller function to handle all forms.

Comment: Will you results be some kind of models? In this case better to use `Form::model`

Comment: Not models but i need user interaction. So form is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no Laravel way of doing this, but you can use HTML basic form arrays to make it work. You need to understand that you have to identify your forms and fields so Laravel knows exactly where the data came from and where to send it back to. If all your fields have the same name how could it possibly know?

**This is a proof of concept that will work straight from your `routes.php` file.**

As I did it all and tested here before posting the answer I used `Route::get()` and `Route::post()`, to not have to create a controller and a view just to test something I will not use. While developing this you will have to put this logic in a controller and in a view, where I think they are alredy in.

To test it the way it is, you just have to point your browser to the following routes:

`http://yourserver/form`

and when you push a button it will automatically POST tho the route:

`http://yourserver/post`

I'm basically giving all forms a number and giving the buttons the number that we will usin in Laravel to get the form data and validate it.

```
Route::get('form', function() 
{
      return Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('post'))).
             Form::text('form[1][name]', null).
             Form::email('form[1][email]', null).
             '<button type="submit" name="button" value="1">submit</button>'.
           Form::close().

            Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('post'))).
              Form::text('form[2][name]', null).
              Form::email('form[2][email]', null).
              '<button type="submit" name="button" value="2">submit</button>'.
           Form::close();           
});
```

And here we get the data, select the form and pass all of it to the validator:

```
Route::post('post', function() 
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $rules = [
            'name'   => 'required',
            'email'  => 'required'
    ];

    $validation = Validator::make($input['form'][$input['button']], $rules);

    return Redirect::back()->withInput();
});
```

This is how you use it in a Blade view, now using 3 forms instead of 2 and you can have as many forms as you need:

```
<h1>Create user1</h2>    
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('post'))) }}
        {{ Form::text('form[1][name]', null) }}
        {{ Form::email('form[1][email]', null) }}
        <button type="submit" name="button" value="1">submit</button>
    {{ Form::close() }}

</h1>Create user2</h1>    
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('post'))) }}
        {{ Form::text('form[2][name]', null) }}
        {{ Form::email('form[2][email]', null) }}
        <button type="submit" name="button" value="2">submit</button>
    {{ Form::close() }}

</h1>Create user3</h1>    
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('post'))) }}
        {{ Form::text('form[3][name]', null) }}
        {{ Form::email('form[3][email]', null) }}
        <button type="submit" name="button" value="3">submit</button>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

And you can even use a loop to create 100 forms in blade:

```
@for ($i=1; $i <= 100; $i++)
    User {{$i}}
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('post'))) }}
        {{ Form::text("form[$i][name]", null) }}
        {{ Form::email("form[$i][email]", null) }}
        <button type="submit" name="button" value="{{$i}}">submit</button>
    {{ Form::close() }}
@endfor
```

Comment: Why this `Route::get`?

Comment: Just edited to clarify Route::get() and Route::post().

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro, thanks for the nice answer. My page might have 2 forms, or might 10 forms depends with database. now, is it possible to use same logic.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro I mean, it will be better to keep form generation within a view

Comment: It's just to illustrate his point about using array-notation form element names; you don't need to take the direct-from-route-closure code as the literal solution.

Comment: @Anam, yes, you can have as many forms as you need. Just edited to add a View example and 100 forms created in a loop. :)

Comment: For my two cents, I use `Input::old('form.$number.email')` to repopulate the old input.

Comment: This works for form filling, but what about displaying the error?? {{$errors->first('body')}}

Answer (score 0):

Use old input with $request->flash().

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#old-input