# Redirect with input Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I am aware of withInput() and its use.

I have implemented this successfully on a page but utilise multiple versions of the same form on a page. What this means is that when my validation fails, it returns the input and fills in ALL forms on the page with the same data!

Is there a way to target a specific form using withInput()?

```
    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return redirect(Route('ROUTENAME', ['id' => $request->id]))
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->withInput($request->all())
            ->send();
    }
```

Form instance one:

```
                    {{ Form::open(['route' => ['ROUTENAME', $data->id]]) }}
                    @component('forms.formname')
                        @slot('title', 'Add')
                        @slot('colour', 'info')
                        @slot('footer')
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">{{ Form::submit(__('btn.submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}</div>
                            </div>
                        @endslot
                    @endcomponent
                    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Form instance two:

```
                            {{ Form::open() }}
                            {{ Form::model($data1) }}
                            @section('title', 'summary')
                            @component('forms.formname')
                                @slot('colour', 'success')
                                @slot('title')
                                    @lang('title.name') #{{ $data1->id }}
                                @endslot
                                @slot('footer')
                                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary"><span
                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> @lang('btn.Update')</a>
                                        <a href="{{ Route('ROUTENAME', ['id' => $data1->id]) }}"
                                           class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                            @lang('btn.Remove')</a>
                                    </div>
                                @endslot
                            @endcomponent
                            {{ Form::close() }}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I am specifically looking to target form instance one with the input data.

---

**Edit 1**

As per suggestion in the comments I implemented this:

```
    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return redirect(Route('ROUTENAME', ['id' => $request->id]))
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with(['failed' => $request->all()])
            ->send();
    }
```

and in the view on form instance one:

```
                    @if(isset($failed))
                        {{ Form::model($failed) }}
                    @endif
```

This makes no difference when submitted and fills all forms with the same data on fail.

Comment: To access the input you'd usually use `old('fieldname')` so if the fieldnames match it should work.

Comment: The field names are the same for both sets, the second instance is running through a foreach and uses model but these are overriden when it redirects back withInput() like so: `{{ Form::text('origin', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'origin']) }}`

Comment: you can use `with(['data' => $request->all()])`

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately this hasn't worked.

Comment: I think I may have a solution, this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715467/laravel-pre-filling-multiple-forms-if-validation-failed appears to be a similar solution however, this requires all fields are named differently. I suspect I am expecting a more elegant solution and will post my answer once I have tested it.